# Problem with Residue Theorem for Laplace Inversion

Tags: residue-calculus, inverse-laplace

Arising out of my analytical solution to the 2-dimensional transient diffusion equation, I have to invert the following Laplace transform to get a surface flux in physical space (I have greatly simplified the notation for the purpose herein) I'd specifically like to know if the logic that I'm using to invoke the Residue Theorem is sound, and how to overcome an issue with the outcome of the evaluation of the residues.

$$
F(s)=\frac{q(s)\sinh[bq(s)]\sinh[ap(s)]}{g(s)}\frac{1}{p(s)}\Biggl[\frac{1}{s+cw}-\frac{1}{s+w}\Biggr]\hspace 2 in [\text{EQN 1}]
$$

where

$$
p(s)=\sqrt{\frac{s}{c}+w}\hspace 1.5in q(s)=\sqrt{s+w}
$$

and

$$
g(s)=q(s)\cosh[ap(s)]\sinh[bq(s)]+\phi p(s)\sinh[ap(s)]\cosh[bq(s)]\hspace 2 in [\text{EQN 2}]
$$

In the above equations, $a,b,c,w$, and $\phi$ are positive real constants with $c>1$ (if it were equal to $1$, I'd be home for an early lunch!)

It is clear from the definitions of $p(s)$ and $q(s)$ that $s=-w$ and $s=-cw$ (corresponding to which $p(s)=0$) are branch points and not poles. Therefore these terms can be combined with the numerator of EQN. $1$, so that  the Laplace transform can be written in the form

$$
F(s)=\frac{N(s)}{g(s)}\hspace 2 in [\text{EQN 3}]
$$

where
$$
N(s)=\frac{q(s)\sinh[bq(s)]\sinh[ap(s)]}{p(s)}\Biggl[\frac{1}{s+cw}-\frac{1}{s+w}\Biggr]\hspace 2 in[\text{EQN 4}]
$$

For $s>-w$, there are no poles of $g(s)$ since the function is strictly positive.

Between the branch points, i.e., for $-cw<s<-w$, we have

$$
g(s)=\bar{q}(s)\cosh[ap(s)]\sin[b\bar{q}(s)]+i\Big[\phi p(s)\sinh[ap(s)]\cos[b\bar{q}(s)]\Bigr]\hspace 2 in [\text{EQN 5}]
$$

where $\bar{q}(s)=\sqrt{-(s+w)}$, and there are no poles in this interval either, since there are no values of $s$ for which $\sin[b\bar{q}(s)]$ and $\cos[b\bar{q}(s)]$ are simultaneously zero, so that both real and imaginary parts vanish.

For $s<-cw$, the denominator of the Laplace Transform is

$$
g(s)=i\Biggl[\bar{q}(s)\cos[a\bar{p}(s)]\sin[b\bar{q}(s)]+\phi \bar{p}(s)\sin[a\bar{p}(s)]\cos[b\bar{q}(s)]\Biggr]\hspace 2 in [\text{EQN 6}]
$$

where

$$\bar{p}(s)=\sqrt{-\Bigl(\frac{s}{c}+w\Bigr)}$$

For $s<-cw$, the denominator function $g(s)$ has an infinitum of poles along the negative real axis all the way between $s=-cw$ and $s=-\infty$. I could now create a closed contour  by setting the $\gamma$ offset in the Bromwich Contour to $0$ and cuts around the branch points as shown below

[image]

**PROBLEMS:**

Assuming that everything above is logically sound, I could then invoke the Cauchy Residue Theorem and evaluate the Laplace Transform by subtracting the contour integrals along the negative real axis. This seems like an inordinate amount of work.

The integration around the branch cut at $s=-cw$ appears problematic as the radius of the circle around it shrinks to zero.

Is there an alternative contour that will let me sidestep the contour integration part, or some other clever workaround?
Any advice on a simpler approach will be deeply appreciated.

One thing that helps is that the real part of the sum of the residues is zero, so that I can skip the Residue Theorem altogether!

Comment: Is there a reason the contour can lie to the left of the branch points?  By default I would assume the contour has to be the right of all singularities.

Comment: As I have sketched it, the "flat" portion of the Bromwich contour does lie to the right of all poles, but to the left of the branch points which must be excluded from the contour to apply the residue Theorem - at least to my understanding.

Comment: Indeed you can't apply the residue theorem when branch points are in the region, but the inversion formula for the Laplace Transform requires the function to be analytic to the right of your vertical line.  Thus you will not be able to obtain your answer purely from the residue theorem.

Comment: Do you mean “to the Left”?  Because the non-analytic branch points which are to the right of the vertical line are outside the closed contour, so I’m confused as to why they would matter.

Comment: They matter in that because they are there, the integral you have set up will not be equal to the inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: So does that mean that the only option is to use contour integration along the negative real axis around both branch cuts and all poles? I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I've modified the contour and reworked the proposed solution approach to include a combination of the Residue Theorem and Contour Integration.